# Is there ANY way to use Google services on a Huawei phone that has them blocked?

Tags: huawei, google-play-services

I just bought a Huawei phone and then realized that google play services had been blocked. So, I tried a workaround by installing the latest version of google play services apk, which doesn't work. The notification showed that google play services needs to be updated. 
Did I do something wrong? If this workaround won't work at all, can I do something else? For example, if I format the phone and install another OS, would that help?

Comment: You can try to register your ANDROID_ID at Google: https://www.google.com/android/uncertified/ This should white-list your device and allow therefore Play Services.

Comment: Sorry for a delayed reply. I don't quite know how to use this method. So I turned to an easier way, using an app called "Device ID", but under "google service framework (GSF)" is written "not found".